# PHP Regex using preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to extract from a string 2 parts and place them inside an array.

```
$test = "add_image_1";
```

I need to make sure that this string starts with "add_image" and ends with "_1" but only store the number part at the very end. I would like to use preg_split as a learning experience as I will need to use it in the future.

I don't know how to use this function to find an exact word (I tried using "\b" and failed) so I've used "\w+" instead:

```
$result = preg_split("/(?=\w+)_(?=\d)/", $test);
print_r($result);
```

This works fine except it also accepts a bunch of other invalid formats such as:
"add_image_1_2323". I need to make sure it  only accepts this format. The last digit can be larger than 1 digit long.

Result should be:

```
Array ( 

    [0] => add_image 

    [1] => 1 

)
```

How can I make this more secure?

Comment: `preg_split` isn't the tool to check a format. `preg_match` is better fitted for this task, and if you want to extract parts, use capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex checks for `add_image` as beginning of string and matches `_`before digit.

**Regex:** `(?<=add_image)_(?=\d+$)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=add_image)` looks behind for `add_image`
- `(?=\d+$)` looks ahead for number which is end of string and matches the `_`.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE0nH7/1)

Comment: ah so that's how you look for exact words, thanks! I was using it all wrong.

Comment: @Mayron: Yes ! you were using `\w+` which means anything in the character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]` repeated several times.

Comment: Besides that I made sure that once a number is encountered after `_` there is not other `character` by marking it end of string by `$`. So patterns like `add_image_1_23`, `add_image_9sd` would not be matched at all.

Comment: I tried using parenthesis around (add_image) but that didn't work. I also tried using "\b" because I heard that was for capturing full sub-strings. But only your method worked.

Comment: `\b` is boundary check. It checks for word boundaries. Read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it :)